# Master card MIGS api

Tags: php, ajax, api, curl, mastercard

I want to integrate the payment partal without displaying the MasterCard interface to user the will only fill their information on my web
here

**my portal**

[image]

and not here

**mastercard portal**

[image]

I am trying to implement CommWeb on my PHP site using curl. It isn't working. I am getting following error message:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    if (!isset($_GET['id']) || !isset($_GET['motif']) || !isset($_GET['code'])){
        die("Invalid request");
    }

    $amount = 10000;
    $id = 2;
    $motif = 'save';
    $action_code = 'ookkk';
    $orderInfo = 'fhhsd'.$id;
    $MerchTxnRef = $orderInfo.'-'.generateMerchTxnRef();
    $accountData = array(
        'merchant_id' => 'TESTID', // for test card
        'access_code' => '77867878', // for test card
        'secret'      => 'TYUJHGFDFGHJ87654567GFDFGHGF' // for test card

    );

    $currency_str = "USD";
    $mult = 100;

    $queryData = array(
        'vpc_AccessCode' => $accountData['access_code'],
        'vpc_Merchant' => $accountData['merchant_id'],
        'vpc_Amount' => 1000000, // Multiplying by 100 to convert to the smallest unit
        'vpc_OrderInfo' => $orderInfo,
        'vpc_MerchTxnRef' => $MerchTxnRef,
        'vpc_Command' => 'pay',
        'vpc_Currency' => $currency_str,
        'vpc_Locale' => 'en',
        'vpc_Version' => 2,
        'vpc_ReturnURL' => ('http://theeventsfactory.biz/the_events_factory/logics/payment_return.php?id='.$id.'&motif='.$motif.'&code='.$action_code),
        'vpc_SecureHashType' => 'SHA256',
        'vpc_CardNum' => '5123456789012346',
        'vpc_CardExp' => '0521',
        'vpc_CardSecurityCode'=> '123'
    );

    // Add secure secret after hashing
    // $queryData['vpc_SecureHash'] = generateSecureHash($accountData['secret'], $queryData);

    // $migsUrl = 'https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcpay?'.http_build_query($queryData);


    $ch = curl_init("https://migs.mastercard.com.au/vpcdps");
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r($response);

}

function generateMerchTxnRef() {
    $txnRef = rand(9, 9999999999999999);

    // Saved in the database associated with the order id

    return $txnRef;
}

function generateSecureHash($secret, array $params) {
    $secureHash = "";

    // Sorting params first based on the keys
    ksort($params);

    foreach ($params as $key => $value)
    {        
        // Check if key equals to vpc_SecureHash or vpc_SecureHashType to discard it
        if(in_array($key, array('vpc_SecureHash', 'vpc_SecureHashType'))) continue;

        // If key either starts with vpc_ or user_
        if(substr( $key, 0, 4 ) === "vpc_" || substr($key, 0, 5) === "user_") {

            $secureHash .= $key."=".$value."&";
        }
    }

    // Remove the last `&` character from string
    $secureHash = rtrim($secureHash, "&");

    //
    return strtoupper(hash_hmac('sha256', $secureHash, pack('H*', $secret)));
}
```

**This is the response i am receiving**

```
vpc_Amount=0&vpc_BatchNo=0&vpc_Locale=en&vpc_Message=Required+field+vpc_Merchant+was+not+present+in+the+request&vpc_TransactionNo=0&vpc_TxnResponseCode=7
```

How will i solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the array to a url encoded string with http_build_query

after setting the queryData array, add

```
$queryData_string = http_build_query($queryData);
```

Then the curlpost would be set to that

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData_string,
```